# Global symbol requires explicit package name issue

Tags: perl

I'm attempting to write a program that will determine if a 7-character string is a palindrome or not, and it keeps throwing me this error. I'm not exactly sure why it's doing it or how to fix it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a 7 character string: ";

chomp (my $pal = <>);

my $size = length($pal);

if ($size == 7) {
        $pal[0] = my $a;   # Here's where it starts throwing errors
        $pal[1] = my $b;
        $pal[2] = my $c;
        $pal[3] = my $d;
        $pal[4] = my $e;
        $pal[5] = my $f; 
        $pal[6] = my $g;   # All the way to down here
        if ($a eq $g) && ($b eq $f) && ($c eq $e) {
            print "PALINDROME\n";
        }
        else {
            print "NOT A PALINDROME\n";
        }
 }
 else {
     print "Your string must contain 7 characters!\n";
 }
```

I am not allowed to use the reverse function in this code. Also, I'm pretty new to Perl, so please keep things basic for me.

Comment: Shouldn't `$pal[0] = my $a` be `my $a = $pal[0]`, and so on? Not that you need those variables; you could just compare `$pal[0] eq $pal[6]`, etc. Or use a loop and don't limit it to seven characters. (And as someone mentioned in a comment that was quickly removed: Don't use `$a` and `$b`.)

Comment: A few other errors... `<>` in this case is (imho) better written as `<STDIN>`. `my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;`. Next, you're using `$pal` as an array, but it's not. Do this: `my @pal = split //, $input;`. Also, you really shouldn't be using `$a` and `$b`... they are special variables internally. Try to fix up what you've got so it runs, then you can refine further with direct comparisons as @Biffen stated.

Comment: Doing what you suggested (comparing `$pal[0]` with `$pal[6]`) didn't solve my issue, as it's still throwing the same error. If I declared `$pal`earlier in the code, than what's the issue?

Comment: @classans You're going to have to show us the *exact* errors, and the corresponding code.

Comment: You should not update your question with parts of answers. It completely throws out all context for the below responses, and new readers will be wondering wtf?!, because the error in your subject won't even appear in a working script.

Comment: `chomp(my $pal = <>); if ($pal=~/^(.)(.)(.).\3\2\1\z/){ print "PALINDROME\n" } elsif (length $pal == 7 ) { print "NOT A PALINDROME\n" } else { print "Your string must contain 7 characters!\n" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$pal` as an array, but it's not. This collects from `STDIN` into `$input`, then transforms that into a `@pal` array which you're operating on. Your `=` variables were backwards, it's recommended not to use `$a` or `$b` as they are special in Perl, and you were missing parens around your `if` statement. This should get you going:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a 7 character string: ";

my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;

my $size = length($input);

my @pal = split //, $input;

if ($size == 7) {
    my $a = $pal[0];
    my $b = $pal[1];
    my $c = $pal[2];
    my $d = $pal[3];
    my $e = $pal[4];
    my $f = $pal[5];
    my $g = $pal[6];
    if (($a eq $g) && ($b eq $f) && ($c eq $e)){
        print "PALINDROME\n";
    }
    else {
        print "NOT A PALINDROME\n";
    }
}
else {
    print "Your string must contain 7 characters!\n";
}
```

Here's an example `if` statement using @Biffen suggestion as your comparison instead of assigning the whole array into single scalars.

```
    if ($size == 7) {
        if ($pal[0] eq $pal[6] && $pal[1] eq $pal[5] && $pal[2] eq $pal[4]){
            print "PALINDROME\n";
        }
        else {
            print "NOT A PALINDROME\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the string `$pal` as an array in perl (one of the many ways that perl is not C).  It'll tell you that `@pal` doesn't exist.  You need to use `substr`, and your assignments are also backwards:

```
    my $c0 = substr($pal, 0, 1);
    my $c1 = substr($pal, 1, 1);
    my $c2 = substr($pal, 2, 1);
    my $c3 = substr($pal, 3, 1);
    my $c4 = substr($pal, 4, 1);
    my $c5 = substr($pal, 5, 1);
    my $c6 = substr($pal, 6, 1);
    if ($c0 eq $c6) && ($c1 eq $c5) && ($c2 eq $c4) {
        print "PALINDROME\n";
    }
    else {
        print "NOT A PALINDROME\n";
    }
```

Using `$a` and `$b` can cause problems, so I've renamed the variables.

Comment: The problem with `$a` and `$b` happens exactly when you *do* use them with `my`: running `perl -E'my $a; sort { $a <=> $b } 0..10'` gives `Can't use "my $a" in sort comparison`.

Comment: You'll only get that if you're sorting.  I agree it's not a good idea to use `$a` and `$b`, but it'll work here.

Comment: Or if you use a number of callbacks from List::Util, etc. It's a bad practice because it *can* cause problems.

Comment: Mark Jason Dominus once wrote: `Being careful does not mean trying to understand the possible consequences while behaving dangerously; it means avoiding dangerous behavior in the first place. Don't say ``I know it's dangerous, so I'll be really careful.'' Say ``I know it's dangerous, so I won't do it.'`

Comment: OK, you guys are right...  Thanks!  I must be getting old: people say, "You shouldn't do that," and I reply, "Watch me!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying slightly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

print 'Enter a 7 character string: ';
chomp(my $string = <STDIN>);

my @pal = split //, $string;

die "$string is not a 7 character string\n"
  if @pal != 7;

for (0 .. 2) {
  if ($pal[$_] ne $pal[$#pal - $_]) {
    say "$string is not a palindrome";
    exit;
  }
}

say "$string is a palindrome";
```